Normal Weight of RC Beam
Is 450kg/m for a reinforced concrete beam outlandish?
The dimensions are:
width: 0.3m
depth: 0.6m
I am designing a beam, and that is what I got.

Do some research: a google search with "https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=mass+of+concrete+beam+per+meter&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8#ip=1" gives plenty of results - some better than others but that is only to be expected.

How much reinforcing? makes a difference.

0.30.62500kg/m^3=450kg. all okay!
